# What does my calculus textbook mean by "cursor"?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to figure out how to get the precise definition of a limit. In the first example of the section "The precise definition of a limit", my textbook says, "find a number $\delta$ that corresponds to $\epsilon = 0.2$ in the definition of a limit for the function $f(x) = x^3 - 5x +6$ with $a = 1$ and $L = 2$.

It briefly mentions how $|(x^3 - 5x) - 2| < 0.2$ can be rewritten in various ways.

Then it says:

> so we need to determine the values of $x$ for which the curve $y = x^3-5x+6$ lies between the horizontal lines $y=1.8$ and $y = 2.2$. Therefore we graph the curves $y = x^3-5x+6$, $y=1.8$, and $y=2.2$ near the point $(1, 2)$ in figure 8. Then we use the **cursor** to estimate the the x-coordinate of the point of intersection of the line $y=2.2$ and the curve $y = x^3-5x+6$" is about $0.911$. Similarly, $y = x^3-5x+6$ intersects the line $y=1.8$ when $x \approx 1.124$. So, rounding toward 1 to be safe, we can say that
>
> if $0.82 < x < 1.12$ then $1.8<x^3-5x+6<2.2$

*What does it mean by "cursor"?*

My textbook's name is "Calculus: Early Transcendentals" by James Stewart. It is the 8th edition. The paragraph cited is from page 107 and 108.

Comment: Without seeing Figure 8, I would guess that the graphs were drawn on a computer screen using software that reports the location of the "mouse pointer" (aka, "cursor") as coordinates. So, hovering the mouse to an apparent point of intersection shows an approximation of the coordinates of that point.

Comment: @Blue I would probably say the same, it's just that it doesn't make sense for a physical textbook to say this.

Comment: Could also be taken from the context of using a graphing calculator to trace a curve.

Comment: @LuminousNutria: I don't disagree. :)  Does this textbook make other references to using software for problem-solving or exploration? Does "Figure 8" look like a screenshot (especially from a graphing calculator, as per Matthew's suggestion)?

Comment: @Blue Thanks, unfortunately, It doesn't reference any software at all. Figure 8 doesn't look like a screenshot or anything like that.

Comment: @bof I have added the textbook's name, edition, and author.

Comment: I used the "look inside" feature on amazon to search for "cursor" in the book.  On page $51$ the author suggests using a graphing calculator to graph a function, and using the cursor to estimate the value at some point.  I'm sure he means the same thing later on in the book.

Comment: @saulspatz Wouldn't estimating mean the definition isn't precise?

Comment: He means that you can't tell exactly what the ordinate value is by looking at the graph, but you can get a good idea.  I don't understand what definition you're referring to.

Comment: @saulspatz I mentioned that name of the section was "the precise definition of a limit".

Comment: The definition of a limit is precise.  It's the $x-$coordinate in this example that isn't precisely known.    (I said "ordinate" in a previous comment, but I should have said "abscissa.")   There is a precise value of the $x-coordinate too, but we don't need to know it exactly.  An approximation is good enough.

Comment: @LuminousNutria: Indeed, the "precise definition of a limit" (using $\epsilon$ and $\delta$) is provided in the blue box on page 106. The surrounding discussion is the author trying to provide an understanding of the definition using approximations.

Comment: @LuminousNutria: To your actual question ... Having taken a look at the Amazon preview of the book, I believe that the rounded box surrounding Figure 8 (and Figure 7 above it) is intended to convey the idea that the graph has been plotted in a software window. (Nevermind that some labels fall outside of that box.) Compare the graphs in, say, Figures 1–6, which are not surrounded by these boxes. Since the book's introduction describes the significant role software will play in the lessons, the author seems to be taking the audience's familiarity with on-screen "cursor"s for granted.

Comment: @Blue Okay, thank you. I guess I was overthinking it. :/